# How run unit test cases once with all different mock data?

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing

It got unit test code like this

```
class SampleControllerTests: XCTestCase {
    
    var sut: SampleViewController!
    
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // ISSUE
        sut = SampleViewController(data: SampleData(value: 0)
    } 
    

    func test_whenInit_isResultValid() {
        XCTAssertEqual(sut.result, someValues)
    }


}


struct SampleData {
    var value: Int
}
```

Say I got test sample data like

- SampleData(value: 0)
- SampleData(value: 1)
- SampleData(value: 2)

How to make all test cases run through all those three sample data with pressing `cmd` + `U` only once?

Comment: If you are testing the `result` that you set with initialization of ViewController, you can create an instance of `SampleViewController` with `SampleData` in test function and assert what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create an array of controllers and iterate over each to run the assertion in your tests.

```
class SampleControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    var controllers: [SampleViewController] = []

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // ISSUE
        let sampleData = (0...2).map(SampleData.init)
        controllers = sampleData.map(SampleViewController.init)
    }


    func test_whenInit_isResultValid() {
        controllers.forEach { sut in
            XCTAssertEqual(sut.result, someValues)
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: This looks like e a good solution and very intuitive, thanks man.